# How do I shift this function to the right by 1?

Tags: graphing-functions

I have the function:

$$y =13000e^{-0.075t}cos\left(\frac{2πt}{4}\right) | 0\le{t}\le{20}$$

Which creates the graph:

[What graphs currently looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgBon.png)

At the moment the largest y value is **13000**, starting at **t = 0** However it is meant to peak at **t = 1** like in the bottom figure. I have tried the following:

$$y =13000e^{-0.075t}cos\left(\frac{2πt}{4}+1\right) | 0\le{t}\le{20}$$
$$y =13000e^{-0.075t}cos\left(\frac{2πt}{4}+2\right) | 0\le{t}\le{20}$$
$$y =13000e^{-0.075t}cos\left(\frac{2πt}{4}+t\right) | 0\le{t}\le{20}$$
$$y =13000e^{-0.075t}cos\left(\frac{2πt}{4}+2t\right) | 0\le{t}\le{20}$$
$$y =13000e^{-0.075t}cos\left(\frac{2πt}{4}+π\right) | 0\le{t}\le{20}$$
$$y =13000e^{-0.075t}cos\left(\frac{2πt}{4}+2π\right) | 0\le{t}\le{20}$$

Plus all the above except subtracting the values. Nothing has been able to correctly shift it so the graph looks like that below.

[What I need the graph to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDDla.png)

Comment: Put $ t \to t-1 $

Comment: I have just tried $$y =13000e^{-0.075t}cos\left(\frac{2π(t-1)}{4}\right) | 0\le{t}\le{20}$$ however the peak is now 12074 rather than 13000.

Comment: You need to change t in exponent of e too, also the domain changes

Comment: Ah of course, I forgot all about that one. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try, $$13000e^{-0.075(t-1)}cos\left(\frac{2π(t-1)}{4}\right) , 0\le{t}\le{20}$$

Comment: Thank you, this works